# Disable an input field with a checkbox and dropdown selection

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 total fields for this. The first is a checkbox. When it is selected the input field should be activated. The second is a dropdown where when a certain selection is selected, the input field should be activated. The third field is the actual input field that needs to only be activated when the checkbox is checked and the dropdown has the certain selection.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkValue">
<select name="select" ng-model="selectValue">
  <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option-3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="option-4">Option 4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" ng-model="inputValue" ng-disabled="!checkValue && selectValue != 'option-1'">
```

Comment: What's the issue ?

Comment: It isn't working correctly. The field is only affected by the first operation: !checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are right in comment , it was bypassing your selectbox model in check. Below thing worked for me in fidde.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="inputValue" ng-disabled="(!checkValue) || (checkValue && selectValue == undefined)">
```

Check fiddle at : http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5106/

More robust scenarios can be added by adding a scope function which controls the  state of input box.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="inputValue" ng-disabled="(!checkValue) || (checkValue && setInputState(selectValue))">

  $scope.setInputState= function(input){
    var state= false;
    if(input === undefined || input != 'option-1'){
        state = true;
    }
    return state;
   }
```

Comment: Whenever the dropdown is changed I would like the disabled field to also update.

Comment: I didn't get you. Whenever dropdown changes disable field will update,

Comment: so whenever the user changes the dropdown while the checkbox is enabled. It should switch to being disabled/enabled based on the selection of the dropdown.

Comment: You can use more option by adding a function in controller which checks for selectbox values. For example in this fiddle your box will be enabled only if option-1 is selected. http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5107/

Comment: Though your function does work I also found that doing it inside the ng-disabled to work as well. Someone made it an answer and deleted it but here is the jfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/me9s2mwp/1/